# Liferay JSON web services visibility in JBoss domain mode

Tags: rest, jboss, jboss7.x, liferay-6

I have deployed Liferay 6.1.1GA2 on JBoss 7.1.3 in domain mode and it works fine.
But now, I have a problem with the REST API visibility (liferay_url/api/jsonws).

If I start JBoss in standalone mode, I can find all the default services, but in domain mode, the list of services is empty. The startup log shows an error message that can be linked with this issue, because the JSON services discovery process searches the @JSONWebService annotation into the classpath:

```
[Server:liferay] 10:30:14,466 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-4) 10:30:14,464 ERROR [MSC service thread 1-4][ClassPathUtil:173] Class com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet is not loaded from a standard location (/WEB-INF/classes)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem will be something related with resolution of the parameters when jboss is starting up in this mode, may be the de properties of the jboss server deployment in managed domain. I don't know the real problem, but you can try to define one jvm by server in the `host.xml` config file, or add parameters to the server specification.

You can override all the parameters that you need using the java option element config described in [this article](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Command+line+parameters?_sscc=t), especially the parameter related to the deployment and data for jboss server default folders.

A possible solution for you will be something like this:

```
  <server name="server-one" group="main-server-group">
     <jvm name="default">
       <jvm-options>
         <option value="-Djboss.domain.deployment.dir=/opt/jboss-7.1.3/domain/servers/server-one/content"/>
       </jvm-options>
     </jvm>
  </server>
```

At startup, the property of deployment folder server will be attached with absolute path, try this or another parameters instead. This workaround will fix another problems related with this kind of issue.